# WPF, How can I only one tick using a DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to have a function that runs once after a few seconds. (The program is not stopped)

So I'm using a `DispatcherTimer` like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TimerStart();
}

DispatcherTimer Timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
int count = 3;
private void TimerStart()
{
    Timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    Timer1.Tick += MyEvent;
    Timer1.Start();
}

void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
    // My code
    (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
    count++;
}
```

In the first `ButtonClick` it runs `MyEvent()` in 3 seconds

The second `ButtonClick` is performed twice and after 3 seconds the `MyEvent()` is called

And on the third time, `MyEvent()` the three runs `MyEvent()`

Why does this happen?

So I tried a different approach, using a Thread:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
            delegate()
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // my code
                count++;
            }));

        thread.Start();
    }
```

But this way, the error occurs in a portion of the MyCode `(this.Usercontrol.Children.RemoveAt(0);)`

> System.InvalidOperationException :
>   Other threads can not be the thread that owns the object, call the object >access

What should I do?

Thank you, regards.

Comment: You could use async/await like `await Task.Delay(3000);`

Comment: Thank you All.I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should understand this code：

```
 Timer1.Tick += MyEvent;
```

`+=` means regist an event. 
For example, In the first ButtonClick, Timer1 regist an event named MyEvent to Tick. And in the second Click, Timer1 regist MyEvent again, it means Timer1 regist MyEvent twice. So you will see MyEvent excutes twice.

You can write code like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer1.Tick += MyEvent;
        Timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Start();
    }

    DispatcherTimer Timer1;
    int count = 3;

    void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
        // My code
        (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
        count++;
    }
```

Timer1 regist MyEvent in Constructer only once, so it will be correct.

Comment: I know what you're talking about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `Timer1.Tick += MyEvent;` from `TimerStart()`. It is causing `MyEvent()` to be registered in the invocation list of `Tick` event everytime you call `TimerStart()`. InvocationList of Tick event will contain as many entries for same function as many time you register it.

Move the event registration to the constructor and it will work fine.